# Can not export a project Android in Eclipse to archive file after remove folder .svn

Tags: android, eclipse, svn, export

I have a project Android in Eclipse +  SVN server.

After i delete some files in .svn or .svn folder.

I can not export the projet to Archive file.
The error notification: "cann't file the file *** in the folder .svn ..."

What should i do to export my project normally ?

THanks

Comment: Why are you deleting files in .svn folder?

Comment: Because.  i don't want to use torturse SVN  server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should start by right clicking your project, choosing the team menu and then disconnect.  After you've done that remove those folders and try your export.

Comment: after disconnect, i delete all the .SVN folder and it worked. Thanks for your help :)